# Media queries are not working after migration to server

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working on a site on a Github repository and I published it live on another server so that I can play around with APIs and databases. After making an exact copy of the Github files and dropping that into the new server, the media queries aren't working on my desktop or mobile. They do however work on Github.

I've tried to clear the cache on both devices, and after doing that, it shrinks down only by directly making the browser window (on my computer) smaller and not going to inspect tools. If I use the inspect tools or use my phone, it is not responsive at all. I was also told it can take 24-72 hours for sites to fully migrate, but don't know if that's the issue since I published it on Sunday night 02/14/21.  I had someone else look at it on their computer and they said it seems to be responsive.

This is the very first site I've published so I don't know the ins and outs yet. What else could it be? I'll post the link to my site and also a screenshot of what it looks like on mobile.[image]

http://creativecog.design/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in the head of your document

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Also why do you have two heads set up and two html elements as this will be causing your issues

Comment: The meta tag is already in the head section.

Comment: Why do you have a nested html in a html as the top section does not have this meta tag, should only have one head section in your html

Comment: I only have one head tag, but I do see the <!DOCTYPE html> and the <html lang="en"> tags. Those two tags are put in automatically by my text editor when I set up my html document using shift+!+tab. Would you get rid of the <html lang="en"> tag?

Comment: Inspecting your code from the link you have supplied, i can see 2 doctypes, 2 heads and 2 html elements, so your current layout in order is doctype->html->head->frameset->frame->doctype->html->head. Inspect the link above in chrome and see if you can replicate this as this will 100% be your issue

Comment: You're very right. My original code definitely does not have that so it must have something to do with the server injecting information into it? Thanks a bunch, this is a whole new world for me. Hmm, where to go from here.

Comment: its hard for me to help diagnose without anymore information about how you are hosting this and what set up you have got going as whatever you have is placing everything in a frameset as i can see your original code at http://Devtestserver.hopto.org doesnt have this frame set

Comment: I'm going to troubleshoot this with my friend who set up the server. Thanks for helping me find the issue.